# Can two different intentservices run concurrently? Does OS wait for first intentservice to stop before starting second intent service?

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

I have two `intentservices`: `IntentServiceA` and `IntentServiceB`.

While `IntentServiceA` is running and if I call `startService(IntentServiceB)` , will `IntentServiceB` run concurrently with `IntentServiceA` or does it wait till `IntentServiceA` stops?

If it was about `Asynctasks` it would be: `AsyncktaskB` won't start till `AsynctaskA` is finished. But I could not find any documentation for this scenario in case of `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at [the `IntentService` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) indicates that each `IntentService` should have its own `HandlerThread` and therefore should run concurrently. That being said, I do not recall ever trying this.

Comment: `@CommonsWare`: I have two Asynctasks viz. AsynctaskA and AsynctaskB. AsynctaskA have high priority than AsynctaskB. So I don't want AsynctaskA to wait till AsynctaskB finishes. Hence I made IntentServiceB to perform same work that AsynctaskB was doing. But here I had doubt (hence problem) about two IntentServices running concurrently as I have IntentServiceA which runs when app receives GCM and have high priority than IntentServiceB and I don't wan't IntentServiceA to wait till IntentServiceB finishes. Hence asked. Thanks for such a quick answer.

Comment: @achavan804: "So I don't want AsynctaskA to wait till AsynctaskB finishes" -- it won't, if you are using `executeOnExecutor()`.